Cumulative product resampling for Pandas Series
I am aggregating data to daily bins. My data has duplicate data points for each day, but not the same second.
Naive resampling and forward filling fails due to non-unique index:
freq = "D"
compounded = compounded.asfreq(freq, method='ffill')

How can apply a custom function for each resampled day to correctly aggregate multiple timepoints within the intraday timeframe?

You can pass a custom function to resampler agg() that takes all the values for the particular day and produces the aggregated values.
Here is an example for cumulative product
        freq = "D"

        # If we haved closed two positions on the same day, asfreq() will fail unless we merge profit values
        def custom_cumprod_resampler(intraday_series):
            match len(intraday_series):
                case 0:
                    return 0
                case 1:
                    return intraday_series.iloc[0]
                case _:
                    # Multiple closed positions within the same day, calculate the daily overall return
                    daily_compounded = intraday_series.add(1).cumprod().sub(1)
                    return daily_compounded.iloc[-1]

        try:
            resampled_returns = returns.resample(freq).agg(custom_cumprod_resampler)
            resampled_compounded = resampled_returns.add(1).cumprod().sub(1)
            resampled_compounded = resampled_compounded.ffill()
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Daily binning failed for: {profit_data}") from e

